# How to Shorten a URL to an SEO Friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use mod_rewrite to shorten a long URL into a more SEO friendly URL. Apache directives, especially mod_rewrite, are not highly intuitive and seem difficult to create. My SO searches did not produce anything that looked similar to what I am trying to achieve here.

I would like to take this URL:

https://example.com/core-application/addons/the-sub-directory

And shorten it to:

https://example.com/the_subdirectory

Nothing lives in or exists in "the_subdirectory" off of the DOCUMENT_ROOT. Everything lives in, exists in and functions/parses in /core-application/addons/the-sub-directory/* off of the DOCUMENT_ROOT.

I want to implement this in my .htaccess file in the document root.

The goal in mind is that when someone requests example.com/the_subdirectory the server processes and parses from /core-application/addons/the-sub-directory/

Comment: I added a softlink (`ln -s core-application/addons/the-sub-directory the_subdirectory`) and that seems to get me what I am looking for. Just wondering if there is any downside or issue with a softlink vs. a mod_rewrite?

Comment: In this situation and if you need just the one, then a softlink will probably do. But you got no way to implement any sort of pattern matching that way, of course.